# How to run SPARQL queries in R (WBG Topical Taxonomy) without parallelization

Tags: sparql, rdf, taxonomy, rdflib

I am an R user and I am interested to use the World Bank Group (WBG) Topical Taxonomy through SPARQL queries.
This can be done directly on the API https://vocabulary.worldbank.org/PoolParty/sparql/taxonomy but it can be done also through R by using the functions load.rdf (to load the taxonomy.rdf rdfxml file downloaded from https://vocabulary.worldbank.org/ ) and after using the sparql.rdf to perform the query. These functions are available on the "rrdf" package

These are the three lines of codes:

taxonomy_file        <- load.rdf("taxonomy.rdf")

query                <- "SELECT DISTINCT ?nodeOnPath WHERE {http://vocabulary.worldbank.org/taxonomy/435 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#narrower* ?nodeOnPath}"

result_query_1               <- sparql.rdf(taxonomy_file,query)

What I obtain from result_query_1 is exactly the same I get through the API.

However, the load.rdf function uses all the cores available on my computer and not only one. This function is somehow parallelizing the load task over all the core available on my machine and I do not want that. I haven't found any option on that function to specify its serialized usege.
Therefore, I am trying to find other solutions. For instance, I have tried "rdf_parse" and "rdf_query" of the package "rdflib" but without any encouraging result. These are the code lines I have used.

taxonomy_file <- rdf_parse("taxonomy.rdf")

query                <- "SELECT DISTINCT ?nodeOnPath WHERE {http://vocabulary.worldbank.org/taxonomy/435 http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#narrower* ?nodeOnPath}"

result_query_2       <- rdf_query(taxonomy_file , query = query)

Is there any other function that perform this task? The objective of my work is to run several queries simultaneously using foreach.

Thank you very much for any suggestion you could provide me.

Comment: To clarify, your objective is to query the loaded RDF file in parallel?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I would like to query taxonomy.rdf in parallel.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is because two things are mentioned: The intensive loading task and the need for parallel queries. To me, the two seem unrelated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As an example: I have a machine with 100 cores.
1) I tried to load the taxonomy.rdf only on 1 core and I realized that the loading operation used all the available cores (100)in my machine. I suppose that the load.rdf function is an already parallelized function.
2) I tried to load the taxonomy.rdf on 50 cores simultaneously (using foreach). Again, the loading operation used all the available cores but more intensively than (1). This is probably due to the fact that I used an already parallelized function to load the taxonomy on multiple (50) cores.

Comment: I would like to query the taxonomy.rdf on 50 cores using sparql.rdf in parallel without the bother of having all the 100 cores used (because of the loading operation). Any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ah thanks for explaining-I would recommend using a fully fledged graph database (GraphDB or Virtuoso, etc) for expensive operations rather than using R's rdflib (which I think you're using but not sure) - which is an abstraction over Redland. You're also using the in-memory triple store which will generally have poor performance for intensive operations. I unfortunately don't know enough about Redland or the R package to give guidance on core restrictions